# JRE throwing NoClassDefFoundError error

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

JRE version - **jre1_6_16**

JRE will throwing `NoClassDefFoundError` while execute the java file .

**Error Message**

Error occurred during initialization of `VM` .

```
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java Virtual Machine is unable to find/load `rt.jar` in your Java installation , which most likely means that it has been deleted or relocated .

My advice is to uninstall and re-install Java altogether .

Comment: Glad to have helped.  You should mark this answer as accepted so that future searchers can find it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got yourself a classpath issue , I suggest checking that you have everything included there .

Comment: i have execute the java file into the jre/bin directory. and checking for only version. i execute this command "./java -version"

Answer (score 1):

What OS is your System running on? I once did this on Fedora 17 and I got this error. It turns out that the RPM wasn't installed properly.

The size of the RPM turns out to be bit smaller than the original size. The solution for you is to **uninstall the JVM and reinstall it**. Then it'll solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me (linux, after install via: `sudo alien -i jdk-7u45-linux-x64.rpm`):

```
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45; export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin (put in /etc/bash_bashrc)

    cd ${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib

../../bin/unpack200 rt.pack rt.jar
```